# Uniform continuous function convergence VS continuous funcition convergence

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence

> Suppose that $f:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ is uniformly continuous. Let
>   $f_n(x)=f(x+1/n)$.
>
> a) Prove that $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $\Bbb{R}$
>
> b) Does this remain true if $f$ id just continuous? Prove it or
>   provide a counterexample.

**My attempt:-**

For a, since $f$ is uniformly continuous, $f(x+1/n)$ exists and $\limsup\left|f_n-f\right|=\limsup\left|f(x+1/n)-f(x)\right|=0$.  Therefore $f_n\to f$ uniformly on $\Bbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $f$ is uniformly continuous, for any $\epsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0$ such that
$$
|x-y| < \delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(y)| < \epsilon
$$
So for $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $1/N < \delta$, it happens that
$$
|f_n(x) - f(x)| < \epsilon \quad \forall n\geq N \quad \forall x\in \mathbb{R}
$$
This gives uniform convergence.

For part (b), take $f(x) = e^x$, then suppose $f_n \to f$ uniformly, then for $\epsilon = 1>0, \exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|f_n(x) - f(x)| < 1$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and $n\geq N$. Choose $M \in \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$
e^x > N \quad\forall x>M
$$
Then for any $x > M$, the mean-value theorem implies that there is some $\zeta \in [x,x+1/N]$ such that
$$
|f_N(x) - f(x)| = e^{\zeta}/N > e^x/N > 1
$$

Answer (score 0):

The example of a function which is continuous but not uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ that you should keep in mind is $f(x)=x^2$. Here you find

$$\left |f_n(x)-f(x) \right |=\left |x^2+2x/n+1/n^2-x^2 \right |= \left |2x/n+1/n^2 \right |.$$

Note the $x$ term can be made large for each fixed $n$. Can you finish from here?

Also I would say that your proof of part (a) is not really complete. You need to argue somewhere that the $N$ you choose for convergence can be chosen to not depend on $x$. This much is not so hard, because uniform continuity tells you that $|f(x)-f(y)|$ can be made small by only controlling $|x-y|$, which for your case is just $1/n$.

Comment: So uniform continuity implies independence of x, and merely continuous implies dependence on x and hence only pointwise convergence?

Comment: Just continuity doesn't necessarily *imply* dependence on $x$, but it makes it possible, as in the example I gave.

Comment: I see, poor choice of words on my part.  It makes sense now, thank you